# Is it safe to use ERC 998 now?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, solidity-0.8.x, erc-1155, smart-contract

I want a functionality in my smart contract where a token ( say an ERC 721 token ) can own other tokens ( ERC 721 , ERC 1155 , ERC 2535 ) .
With some research I got to know about ERC 998 . I checked for official documentation and found status as 'stagnant'.
Can I use it now ? Asking this because it is written there that  " This EIP had no activity for at least 6 months . This EIP should not be used . "
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not safe to use. Please see this page https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-998 and the STAGNANT warning at top.

This means there is no consensus on this protocol and it is very unlikely that if you build it then other people will be able to connect with it.

---

But, if you will not depend on other things working with your project (e.g. wallets, marketplaces, other tokens) then you are fine to study those ideas and implement them.

Here is an example of NFTs that can split into more NFTs in a hierarchal structure https://web.archive.org/web/20220316135327/https://area.world/ and the code is public https://github.com/LightArtists/area-ethereum-contracts

An important part of that implementation was to reduce the gas cost of minting 400 tokens at a time.

Comment: Office hours: if you want to go over specific design details for your project, I have a weekly can set up to help with stuff like that, you are welcome to join https://phor.net/#hour